# Magento 2.0.2 installation on shared server - Stuck at 66%

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I've been having a nightmare with Magento 2 installation on shared server. The thing is that I don't have problems with shared server. I can get as much resources and config as Magento needs.

But it gets stuck on 66% and this is Console log:

```
    Module 'Magento_Directory':
    Installing data.. 
    [ERROR] exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=47710 in 
/home/gottstor/public_html/store/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228' in /home/gottstor/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
    Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Error while sen...', '/home/gottstor/...', 228, Array)
    #1 /home/gottstor/public_html/store/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #2 /home/gottstor/public_html/store/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #3 /home/gottstor/public_html/store/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #4 /home/gottstor/public_html/store/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
```

I did install it on localhost with no issues. But can't get it work on Shared Hosting.

Max execution time is set to 60, max allowed packet in MySQL set to 268M, max_input_vars 5000, memory_limit 512M.

I have searched the web, posted on Magento forums, with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn;t the solution, but max_execution_time should be set to more than 60, I'd recommend 300 for Magento sites...

Comment: Increase memory_limit to at least 768M

Comment: @SteveJohnson - memory_limit on my local php is set to 128M and Magento 2 installed smoothly. What is the point of setting 768M on hosting, if Magento installed with settings of 128M?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly but things like installing sample data or importing products consume a lot of memory.

Comment: @SteveJohnson thanks for your reply, the fact is that I'm installing just Magento 2, no sample data. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it is about timeout issue.

1. remove `var/.maintenance.flag`
2. remove `app/etc/config.php` & `env.php`
3. cleanup you DB.
4. in `php.ini`, set `max_execution_time=500`
5. run yourmagento.com again

Done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I managed to install magento, just told my hosting company to optimize my server for Magento, and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your php memory_limit should be sufficient, like 2028M.
this helps in my case .

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your php.ini file in your PHP root. (*mine is c:\php\php.ini*)
2. Find `max_execution_time` and set to 200 or 300. (*mine original was 60*)
3. Go to your created database, remove all the tables.
4. Restart your server. (*mine is apache*)
5. Repeat your installation steps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem. Magento installation stoped on `Installing data..`

Run this script `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

It helped me and magento site srtarted to work. (I just closed installation page)

Answer (score 0):

- `max_execution_time 500`
- Try to increase your ram as well if you are using virtual machine
- Restart the installation.

Regards,