# Magento installation stuck on Magento_Catalog

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to install magento 2.1.3 but the installation stops at 53% at:

> Module 'Magento_Catalog':
>   Installing data...

With the error in console:

> POST http://local.magento/setup/index.php/install/start 500 (Internal Server Error)

And my magento/var/log/debug.log file showing:

> [2017-01-07 11:07:38] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://local.magento/setup/index.php/install/start","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []

My memory and execution time is set to:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
max_execution_time = 18000
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

My magento installation stuck on 73% - `Installing data..` i think these problems are similar.

Run this script `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

It helped me and magento site srtarted to work. (I just closed installation page)
also this can be helpful [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218372/magento-2-0-2-installation-on-shared-server-stuck-at-66/44071968#44071968)